# Ignore/Mask certain labels Softmax Cross-entropy

Tags: python, tensorflow, cross-entropy, dependency-parsing

In trying implement the cross entropy loss with l2 regularization described here [A Fast and Accurate Dependency Parser using Neural Networks](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D14-1082), I get the error: `ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (48,) for Tensor u'Placeholder_2:0', which has shape '(48, 1)` after getting a negative loss for a few steps in training. My loss is as follows:

```
self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=self.prediction, labels=self.train_labels)) 
         + 1e-8 * (tf.nn.l2_loss(w1) 
         + tf.nn.l2_loss(w2))
```

and is a negative value at step 0. I believe my problem is that some labels are -1 and should be ignored as stated in the paper: "A slight
variation is that we compute the softmax probabilities
only among the feasible transitions in
practice". How would I go about ignoring these labels when calculating the loss?

Comment: problem is with placeholder shape and what you are storing in the placeholder

Comment: I managed to fix the error but i am still getting a negative loss